# Encode UTF-8 for Django form

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-unicode

I have a contact form

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=100, label=_('firstname'))
    mail = forms.EmailField(required=True, max_length=150, label=_('mail'))

def display(request):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid(): 
       ...
    else:
       form = ContactForm()  

    return render_to_response('contact.html', {'contact_form' : form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

With `from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _`

In my template `contact.html`

```
<form action="#" method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
    {{ contact_form.as_p  }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I have this error

> 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 2: ordinal
>   not in range(128)
>
> Unicode error hint
>
> The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: Prénom

The problem is `_('firstname'))`. But it works when

- I put `.encode('utf8')` at the end it's solved.
- I use the string without the translation tool
- I use another text like `_('other string')`
- I add string at the end : `_('firstname')+''`
- I use the translation in the view : `{% trans "firstname" %}`

But I don't want to do this in all attributs of my contact form (which contains more attributs).

**How can I do that for name and email both ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**THE SOLUTION** is to replace `gettext_lazy` by `ugettext_lazy` because the string `Prénom` contains a special unicode letter `é`

Answer (score 1):

Type on the first line:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Python recognises this line as instructions of encoding type for your entire file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify whether you use ModelForms or not, but can you check in your template that your browser will correctly encode the submitted data with the `content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'` attribute in the `form` tag? Like:

```
<form action='/someurl' method='post' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
```

Comment: If I add this content attribute, nothing change. And I use forms.Form to create my form

Comment: Can you post the code of your entire project somewhere? Then I can step through it see what causes the error.

Comment: What do you know/see exactly ? I forgot to see, all work if I display `_('firstname')` outside of form

Comment: I'd like to reproduce your error, so I can find the cause of it. At this moment, I don't have enough information - I can't run your code because I haven't got it. If it's a proprietary project which you cannot share, I'm afraid I can't help you at this moment. Alternatively, you could make a minimum Django project that illustrates the error and that _can_ be shared.

Comment: I added more explanations on the original post

Comment: Do you have enought informations @Michiel Overtoom ?

Comment: Negative, I need a minimal application which reproduces the error. I'm willing to make an effort debugging the problem, but not if I first have to try to recreate your error. I also don't know what you have in your translation files. Please supply me with something that I can readily run and shows the problem.